# Button makes a form input that can be outputed into php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So I'm trying to make a button that when clicked makes a new form input, each form input must have a different name though so I'm able to output it in PHP.

Right now I have this button:

```
<button type="button" class ="btn btn-primary" name="addDom">Add</button>
```

When it is clicked it makes a new form input with:

```
$("button[name='addDom']").click(function() {
                var domElement = $('<div class="form-group"><label for="time">Time assessed:</label><input type="text" name="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Time assessed HH:MM"></div>');
                $(this).after(domElement);
            });
```

The thing is I need the name of every newly created form input to have a different name (Maybe by increments) so I can output it like this:

```
<?php   
                        echo 
                            $_POST["time0"].
                            $_POST["time1"].
                            $_POST["time2"].
                            $_POST["time3"].
                            $_POST["time4"].
                            $_POST["time5"];
                        ?>
```

Any ideas how to make this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `array-like` names => `name='time[]'`

Comment: you can take a global variable counter in JS which is incremented after creating each new element... attach that incremented value of counter in the name of that element while creating